# Which groups or individuals acted against the ceasefire and prisoner exchange at the High Court of Israel?

Tags: israel, palestine, 2023-israel-hamas-war

I know that in the government it was only the Otzma Yehudit party who was against. The Religious Zionist Party, while [being critical](https://jpost.com/israel-news/article-774451), did not vote against. However, [according to Haaretz](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-11-23/ty-article-live/israel-no-hostage-release-before-friday-gaza-cease-fire-also-put-on-hold/0000018b-fa3e-dafe-a18f-fb7f7d420000)

> Israel's High Court rejected two petitions on Thursday filed against the prisoner exchange deal between Israel and Hamas, determining that there is no justification for the court's intervention.

Who submitted these petitions to the High Court? Did they come from the political parties or just some private individuals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Court has so far rejected three petitions, one on November 22nd, and the two referred to in the question on November 23rd.

The first, [rejected on Wednesday the 22nd](https://www.hidabroot.org/article/1188716), was filed by the Al-Magor Terror Victims Association, joined by the Schijveschuurder family who were bereaved by 2001 Sbarro restaurant bombing.

The second petition was filed by the 'We Choose Life' organisation, joined by Herzl and Merav Hajaj, who lost their daughter in a Hamas attack, and Eliyahu Livman, whose son has been taken hostage in Gaza. This was [dismissed at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJCCX.png) as the third petition, filed by a group of Jerusalem residents, as well as the Deputy Mayor of Jerusalem, Aryeh Itzhak King.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that the "terror victim association" does not encompass most victims of acts of terror, nor even most victims of acts of terror by Palestinians. It's kind of a right-wing political lobby group with prominent members/founders who have experienced acts of terror. I think it's actually rather small but I haven't determined the size of its membership.

Comment: @einpoklum: [indeed](https://www.timesofisrael.com/slain-arab-teen-added-to-terror-victims-monument/).